# Determine how close two periodic functions will get to each other?

Tags: algorithms

I'm working on an algorithm for determining scheduling conflicts. I can describe the times that a recurring event occurs at with:

$$time = period \times integral + origin$$

Given two recurring events described by this equation, is there an algorithmic way to determine what the closest the start times will ever be?

I can do this in python code with a brute force loop like this:

```
def computeNearest(period1, offset1, offset2, period2):
    t1 = offset1
    t2 = offset2
    best = inf
    for attempt in range(10000):
        while t1 + period1 < t2:
            t1 += period1
        while t2 < t1:
            t2 += period2
        ahead = t2 - t1
        best = min(best, ahead)
        if best == 0:
            return best
    return best
```

But thats lots of cycles. I feel like I should be able to determine this in one go mathematically. I got as far as:

Given

$$t_1 = p_1 \times n_1 + o_1$$
$$t_2 = p_2 \times n_2 + o_2$$

Given a $t_1$, the nearest cycle where $t_2$ would occur would be

$$n_{2 nearest 1} = \lceil {{t_1 - o_2} \over p_2} \rceil $$

so I can compute the delta as

$$\Delta t = (p_1 \times n_1 + o_1) - (p_2 \times \lceil {{t_1 - o_2} \over p_2} \rceil + o_2)$$

If memory (and a little internet searching) serve right, I should be able to find the minimum, by taking the derivative. However, I have no idea how to take the derivative of a ceiling operation. So am I lost? Or just barking up the wrong tree? I feel like there's a mathematical insight that I've just been out of school too long to remember or something.

Comment: I wish downvotes came with an explanation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is break down all times (periods, origin/offset) into an integer multiple of a smallest scheduling unit. I assume 1 min will be approprpriate here, but it can be seconds or hours or whatever fits what you are modeling.

1. Find the gcd (greatest common divisor) of period1 and period2 (remember that those values are now positive integers). If you get stuck, take a look here: [Euclid's Algorithm in many computer languages](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/).

This is the smallest time distance (in scheduling units) that those 2 events would occur that is different from $0$ and under the assumption that they start at the same time.

2. Find the remainder of |offset2 - offset1| (absolute value of the difference) when divided by the above determined gcd. Call it the effective offset.
3. Well, your minimum time distance will either be the effective offset or (gcd - effective offset), whatever is shorter.

The reasoning for this is that the time difference between event2 that happens after $x_1$ periods and event 1 that happens after $x_2$ periods is

$$o_2+x_2p_2 - (o_1 + x_1p_1) = (o_2 - o_1) + (x_2p_2 - x_1p_1), $$

if $o$ stands for the offsets and $p$ for the periods.

It can be shown that the last term $(x_2p_2 - x_1p_1)$ reaches exactly the integer multiples of gcd ($p_1,p_2$), so that's why the smallest distance is either the effective offset or (effective offset - gcd). All other values are farther away from 0, in either direction.

I also follows that even if you don't know the offsets, the minimal time distance is at most half of the gcd value.

A few examples:

A) offset1=offset2=0, period1=period2=10

A no brainer, but let's go through the motions:

1. gcd (10,10) = 10
2. |0-0| mod 10 = 0
3. Your minimal distance is 0.

B) offset1=15 offset2=4, period1=period2=10

1. gcd (10,10) = 10
2. |4-15| mod 10 = 9
3. Your minimal distance is 1.

Easily verifed that event 1 happens at 15 and event 2 at 14.

C) offset1=1 offset2=3, period1=6, period2=9

1. gcd (6,9) = 3
2. |3-1| mod 3 = 2
3. Your minimal distance is 1 (minimum of 2 and 3-2).

Easily verifed that event 1 happens at 13 and event 2 at 12.

ADDED: In the comments the question came up to find out which event is first when  they are nearest to each other.

The answer is that the shortest time event2 will happen after event1 is the remainder of $(\text{offset}2-\text{offset}1)$ (this time we care about the sign of the difference) when divided by the gcd found in step 1.

Note that we need the **non-negative** remainder $r$ with $0 \le r < \text{gcd}$. IIRC, Python, when asked to calculate $(-6)\%5$ will give you the result $-1$, when $4$ is what is needed here. You may need to adjust for that if the difference of offsets is negative.

So event2 will come after event1 $r$ scheduling units when they are shortest in this order. Event1 will come after event2 $(\text{gcd}-r)$ scheduling units when they are shortest in that order. So depending on if $r$ is smaller, equal or bigger than $\frac{\text{gcd}}2$, event1 will lead before event2, they have the same time distance no matter the order or event2 will lead before event1.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to push it to integer space, because that gets into whether I need big int implementations. But I'll give this a go, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to discern which event is leading the other? I compared my implementation of the above to the brute force one I originally played with, and in the brute force there's a precedence between the two. IOW, what is the closest that event2 will ever occur after the most recent event1. Based on the comparisons I did, it seems that this (excellent) solution you posted just tells me how close either will get to each other.

Comment: @TravisGriggs The answer is effectively 0 if you don't have rational quotients between periods. If one thing happens every hour and the other every $\sqrt{2}$ hours, they get as near as possible as you want, infinitely often, regardless of their initial offset. I'll come back to your second question when I've a bit more time!

Comment: @TravisGriggs See my addition for the "order" of events in their shortest distance.

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm. Python3 at least, does do the right thing with the modulus. I wish I had more points on this exchange, I'd throw you a bounty for the help. :D